# How to use Validators for number range?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, validation

I want the `recipient` variable to be in a range between 1 and 10. I tried it with `Validators.min(1)` and `Validators.max(10)`, which doesn't work. If the user gives an invalid input, I want to return an error message for the user.

How do I use Validators correctly?

TS:

```
  form: FormGroup;
      id: number;
      sender: number;
      recipient: number;
      amount: number;
      fee: number;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SendTXDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {

    this.sender = data.sender;

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: [this.id, Validators.required],
      sender: [this.sender, Validators.required],
      recipient: [this.recipient, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(10)]],
      amount: [this.amount, Validators.required],
      fee: [this.fee, Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  /** This method is used to close the dialog and to send the information back to the component, which
   * called the dialog. **/
  save() {
      this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
  }

  /** This method is used to close the dialog. **/
  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="example-container">
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Transaktion senden</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="form">

  <p>Sender</p>
  <div>
    <p matInput placeholder="Sender">{{ sender }}</p>
  </div>

  <mat-form-field hintLabel="Empfänger zwischen 1 und 10">
    <input matInput #input placeholder="Empfänger" formControlName="recipient"
    required min="1" max="10">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field hintLabel="Betrag darf Ihr Guthaben nicht überschreiten">
    <input matInput #input placeholder="Betrag" formControlName="amount"
    required>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field hintLabel="Je höher die Gebühr, desto wahrscheinlicher und schneller wird Ihre Transaktion gemint">
    <input matInput #input placeholder="Gebühr" formControlName="fee"
    required>
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="close()">Zurück</button>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="save()" cdkFocusInitial>Senden</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't use any `mat-error` and you don't use a condition on your button. Have you read the documentation for both reactive forms and material form fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `type=number` to your input

if its a template driven form to add pattern to the HTML ;

```
  pattern="^[1-9]?"
```

Answer (score 0):

To display message, need to capture error and display it

In this example

Minimum 1
                    


            Maximum 10

Answer (score 0):

use regex patterns if u want to restrict the number to be range from [1-9]
is it only single  number: if so

```
Validators.pattern('^[1-9]?');
```

this may work

Answer (score 0):

Just ask the form if it is valid.

```
save(): void {
    if(!this.form.valid) {
      this.displayMessage();
    } else {
      // actually save
    }
  }
```